# socket io event fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have searched similar questions here but none of them work for me.

I know some people recommend not to use socket inside another event but I had no clue how to trigger socket whenever there is an event.

So I have initialized socket inside another event which is updated every time something happens. But socket connection repeats the previous result with every new update.

I tried initializing socket within componentDidMount lifecyle and it simply does not work.

```
class UploadComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      endpoint: "http://localhost:3000",
    }

    this.uploadModal = this.uploadModal.bind(this);
  }

  uploadModal () {

     update.on('success', file => {
          let {endpoint} = this.state;
          let socket = socketIOClient(endpoint, {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});

          socket.on('data', (mydata) => {
            console.log(mydata) // <-- This gets fired multiple times.
          })
      })

   }

// some more code //
}
```

I want to trigger socket whenever "update" event is fired without message duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can guarantee `success` is called only once, then you'll need to initialize the socket connection / event handler outside this function

```
class UploadComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    const endpoint = "http://localhost:3000";
    this.state = { endpoint };

    this.uploadModal = this.uploadModal.bind(this);
    this.socket = socketIOClient(endpoint, {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
    this.socket.on('data', (mydata) => {
        console.log(mydata)
    })
  }

  uploadModal() {
    update.on('success', file => {
     // this.socket.emit perhaps?  
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: success is called whenever I upload a file. If I upload 5 files together, then it will be called 5 times. And I want to trigger socket every time a file is uploaded successfully.

Comment: @TedKhi when you say "trigger socket", do you mean you want to send an event to the server or do you want to receive something from the server via `data` event?

Comment: I want to receive from server via data event. Because server sends data whenever a file is landed there.
updata.on('success') event confirms the client that file is successfully uploaded.

Comment: @TedKhi in that case then what I've suggested would work. Set the socket up once in the constructor (or even externally and pass in props, whatever makes sense) and you won't create multiple events. The success event doesn't need to be there if you can rely on data being received via `data` regardless.

Comment: Do you know why io.on('connection', ...) at server side was waiting for the component to remount before sending the data?

Comment: Most likely because there was no client available to receive the data - but to that point, when you say "waiting for it to remount", are you suggesting that when you first mount the Component the socket connection isn't established? This wouldn't be what I'd expect....

Comment: I think I was unnecessarily waiting for the connection on server side. 

"""The success event doesn't need to be there if you can rely on data being received via data regardless. """"  

This clicked me and I found that I shouldn't wait for the connection to be established.

Comment: And yes, the socket connection is not established on first mount

Comment: @TedKhi well I can't answer why that's the case because the constructor of a component runs even before it's mounted, so my guess would be there's something going on in `socketIOClient` that's perhaps not ready in time.

Answer (score 1):

As sockets are emitting multiple times on Angular with nodejs happened the same with me for sockets, i tried by removing the socket listeners by `this.socket.removeListener( "Your On Event" );`,

This helped me solved the issue of multiple socket calls, try it, it may help !

Answer (score 0):

As **James** have suggested I have put my socket logic in the constructor. But it was only being fired after my component remounts.

After looking at my nodejs server code I tried to replace

```
// some code //
io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.emit('data', { 
              image: true, 
              buffer: imageBuffer.toString('base64'),
              fileName: meta.name
  })
})
```

with this

```
// some code //
io.emit('data', { 
   image: true, 
   buffer: imageBuffer.toString('base64'),
   fileName: meta.name
})
```

and it works!

Also I had to close socket in componentWillUnmount to avoid multiple repeated data.